# No operations defined in spec! in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an ASP.NET Core Web API. I am getting error when I am trying to run the application.

Here is my controller code:

```
using AllQAs.Api.Manager.User;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AllQAs.Api.Controllers
{
    public class UserController: ApiController
    {
        private IUserManager _userManager;

        public UserController(IUserManager userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsers()
        {
            var users = await _userManager.GetUsers();

            if (users == null)
            {
                return NotFound(); 
            }

            return Ok(users);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [ControllerBase class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#controllerbase-class) , we use   ControllerBase not  ApiController.